# logging a file that keeps changing names

Tags: powershell

I'm running into some dilemma, I have script1 that calls for Script2 in itself.
now script2 runs and calls an XML file, once it is done it creates a log file that changes names every time it is run.

Like so..

```
Remove-StallUserObjects_201903141219.log
Remove-StallUserObjects_201903141222.log
Remove-StallUserObjects_201903141255.log
```

basically it makes a new log file with the given time at the end.
now script1 needs to look into script2's log file and output its own log file that it filtered through.

NOW, my main problem is I don't know how to get my script1 to look into script2s log output but I dont know how as the name keeps changing. and I cant put Remove-StallUserObjects_* because it wont pickup the most recent one.

long story short help

Comment: filter the list by BOTH the prefix and the LastWriteTime - that will give you the newest file. ///// or, it the timestamp in the file name is really a timestamp ... use that to select the newest file by sorting on `.BaseName`. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time stamps embedded in your `Remove-StallUserObjects_*` files are formatted in a way that *alphabetical* sorting will result in the same order as *chronological* sorting by the embedded time stamps.

Therefore, you can take advantage of `Get-ChildItem`'s alphabetically sorted output and simply grab the *last* file returned:

```
$newestLog = @(Get-ChildItem -Filter Remove-StallUserObjects_*.log)[-1]
```

<sup>Note: The `@(...)` prevents an error message in case no files match; 
in that case, `$newestLog` will be `$null`. Up to version 2 of PowerShell you also need the `@(...)` to handle the case when only *1* file matches.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

here's one way to get the newest file from the list of files. it presumes the last part of each `.BaseName` is a time stamp.

```
# fake getting a list of files
#    in real life, use Get-ChildItem
$FileList = @(
    [System.IO.FileInfo]'Remove-StallUserObjects_201903141219.log'
    [System.IO.FileInfo]'Remove-StallUserObjects_201903141222.log'
    [System.IO.FileInfo]'Remove-StallUserObjects_201903141255.log'
    )

# this presumes the last part of each file name is a time stamp
$FileList |
    Sort-Object -Property {$_.BaseName.Split('_')[-1]} |
    Select-Object -Last 1
```

output ...

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
darhsl       1600-12-31   6:00 PM                Remove-StallUserObjects_201903141255.log
```

however, there is a more direct method ... simply sort by the `.CreationTime` or the `.LastWriteTime`.

Answer (score -1):

You have to keep the result of script2 instead of reading logs. Try to create one function : https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/powershell-functions-reusability-restartability-azure/

Comment: Please avoid (external) link only answers and read [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).